# remove hash from angular 8 website URL website not working if I remove simply?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular8

I have developed a website using Angular 8 https://newcondosgta.ca/#/

when I developed this it was without # hash sign but when I refresh the page it was not loading and showing errors in console...but When I assign # hash solution to routes it working perfectly but hash is not looking good in the website.

please suggest me any solution to remove this sign from url...how I can remove this and it will work properly.

thanks

Comment: hi manjeet, did you got any solution then for this issue. Let me know if you fixed it in any way .

Answer (score 0):

use PathLocationStrategy into app.module.ts

```
providers: [
// Below line is optional as default LocationStrategy is PathLocationStrategy
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy} ]
```

Regards